# How to remove whitespace and carriage return symbols in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, whitespace, carriage-return

Whenever I edit a Python or ELisp script, Emacs will display a '$' for every carriage return and a centered dot for every whitespace. I have no idea how to disable or get rid off this setting. After looking on Google, I tried to disable the local and global whitespace modes but had no luck.

I tried to comment out every possible line in my .Emacs file, and when this didn't work I deleted the .Emacs file in my home path entirely. I am running Emacs 24.2 on OSX 10.7.

Does anybody have any idea what I can do to remove these characters ?

Comment: `whitespace-mode` isn't enabled by default, so *something* in your site or user config is enabling it. You can run `emacs -Q` to start with only default settings, to confirm this.

Answer (score 3):

You can get the full documentation here :

http://emacswiki.org/emacs/WhiteSpace

> To deactivate WhiteSpace locally, type: C-u 0 M-x whitespace-mode RET
>
> To deactivate WhiteSpace globally, type: C-u 0 M-x > global-whitespace-mode RET

Comment: I did precisely that, and while it worked for say Org mode, it doesn't do anything when I am editing a Python or Lisp file.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve this by doing the following:

M-x customize
In the edit field I entered 'whitespaces'.

This brought me to a settings menu where I was able to set global-whitespace-mode to 'nil'.

Now, I love my EMACS again....